# mootools element.src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mootools

I am trying to decipher the following code

```
function add_img(el) {
        el.addEvents({
            'mouseenter':  function() {
                var source = el.src;
                if (!(source.match("_active")))
                {
                    var newSource = source.replace(/_off/, "_on");
                    el.src = newSource;
                }
            }...
```

I was assuming el.src would change the img src of the element but instead it is accessing and changing the class, I cannot find src in documentation of mootools anywhere.. why is class getting changes instead of src?

Comment: what is being passed to add_img? if it's an img element, el.src = 'foo' would change the src of the image.

Comment: it is an image element, strangely it is appending _on after class name and not touching src

Comment: I made a [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxHV5/) with the code you've provided.  I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`src` is an attribute on an HTML `img` element.  Its the path to the image.

Comment: yes I am aware of that, the question is that for some reason the class and not the image src are getting changed